# What are my options for plugging leaking gaps, cracks or seams from the back, in concrete walls?

Tags: concrete, waterproofing, caulking

What type of product are available to plug larger gaps in concrete walls, which are subject to hydrostatic pressure (e.g. wet dirt on one side)?

Specifically I have an 18" tall retaining wall type foundation filled with clay soil and always wet due to a spring.  The drain area just happens to be at a seam between an older and newer foundation section, and that's right where water seeps through.  The gap is large, and presumably will move over time.  I have access to both sides.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hydraulic patch product for concrete that is supposed to work for that sort of problem.  It is sold in big box home improvement shops, and seems to be working in my basement.  You can then paint across it with something like Drylock to seal the concrete.  If you can run a drain low enough, there is also a membrane used to waterproof basements, it is applied to the wet side (outside on a basement wall) to allow water easy access to the drain at the bottom.  Stone and dirt then gets filled back in.